# Is it possible to solve a differential equation without analytical term?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been confused by this differential equation for several days. I have an equation like this:

$$my''(t) = cV'(y(t)) - n y'(t)$$

Where $m,c,n$ are known parameters. And $V(y(t))$ is a two dimensional coordinate data set $(y(t_1),V_1),(y(t_2),V_2),...,(y(t_i),V_i)$ and I don't know the exact analytical expression of $V(t)$. So, is it possible to solve this differential equation? By what kind of method or algorithm?

I know maybe I could solve this equation by fitting the data set $V(y(t))$, and obtain an analytical expression, then substitute it into the equation and solve it. But that maybe inaccurate and sometimes it is difficult to fit the curve. So is it possible to solve this kind of equation that contains a term without analytical expression in other methods?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sounds like finite difference method would work here. Let me check if I understand your problem: you want to solve that numerically on a grid?

Comment: @Finn Yes, I want to solve it numerically. But I don't know what does the grid means ?

Comment: The wording of the problem is still ambiguous. I suppose that $V'(y)$ means $\frac{dV}{dy}$ but not $\frac{dV}{dt}$, true or not ? . Clearly $(y_1,V_1),(y_2,V_2),...,(y_i,V_i)$ are known numerical values. But $t_1,t_2,...,t_i$ are, or are not, known numerical values ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Yes, $V'(y)$ means $\frac{dV}{dy}$, and $t1,t2,...$ are all unknown, y(t) is a function of t which I want to obtain from the equation.

Comment: Maybe some family of spline functions could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you idea on how to solve it numerically:

First, there are 3 different options:

1. Finite-Difference method
2. Finite-Element method
3. Finite-Volume  method

2 and 3 are actually the same but they are so much more complicated than finite-differences and that should work fine.

I will  make an example with an easier equation (heat equation):

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t} =\lambda \cdot \dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2} $$

First, let's define the space on which we want to solve our equation. In this case, you should think about a two dimensional grid. x on the first axis and t on the second axis. (y is not an axis, its the value at a given point).
This grid will be divided into nodes and we solve our equations for these nodes. E.G. the derivative at a node can be calculated using the values of the nodes around it. Depending on the taylor expansion, your terms might look different and have different advantages but I wont talk about that here because that's to complicated.
Furthermore, we want a grid with constant distances on the x and t direction ($\Delta t$, $\Delta x$)

Then, we will write down a taylor expansion for every term that we cannot express (we dont want to have any derivatives). Furthermore, the indices look like this:
$$y^n_{i,k,..}$$ $n$ is the time index, and $i,k$ are the spacial indices. (We only need i here, because we only got x).
Furtermore, we will solve our equation for one timestep and once we solved that, we can solve for the next time step (we dont want to solve all the time_steps at the same time).

We will end up with something like this (evaluated at $n+1$ and $i$)
$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\Big|_{n+1, i} \approx \dfrac{y^{n+1}_i-y^n_i}{\Delta t}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}\Big|_{n+1, i} \approx \dfrac{y^{n+1}_{i+1}-2y^{n+1}_{i}+y^{n+1}_{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$

Plugging this back into our initial equation:

$$\dfrac{y^{n+1}_i-y^n_i}{\Delta t} = \lambda \dfrac{y^{n+1}_{i+1}-2y^{n+1}_{i}+y^{n+1}_{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$

We want to write every unknown on the LHS(Assuming that we solved for timestep n and want to solve for timestep n+1):

$$\dfrac{y^{n+1}_i-y^n_i}{\Delta t} = \lambda \dfrac{y^{n+1}_{i+1}-2y^{n+1}_{i}+y^{n+1}_{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$

$$\Rightarrow y^{n+1}_i-y^n_i = \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x} \left( y^{n+1}_{i+1}-2y^{n+1}_{i}+y^{n+1}_{i-1} \right)$$

$$\Rightarrow y^{n+1}_i \cdot \left( 1 + 2 \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}\right)  - \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}y^{n+1}_{i+1}-\dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}y^{n+1}_{i-1}=  y^n_i$$

This equation is really nice because its linear and that's all we need to have at the end. It is an equation that brings together the nodes at the next timesteps and values that we calculated at before. Let's say you want to solve for timestep 2 (and you know values for timestep 1 (also known as initial conditions)) you can write that down for all your nodes in your grid for timestep 2:

Now there is still a problem, because we cannot actually use that equation for ALL our nodes because it takes into account the node left and right of a node. If we talk about boundary nodes, this would not work.

So e.g. We take a grid with 4 nodes in x direction (labeled 1 to 4), and want to solve for timestep 2:

$$\Rightarrow y^{2}_2 \cdot \left( 1 + 2 \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}\right)  - \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}y^{2}_{3}-\dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}y^{2}_{1}=  y^1_2$$
$$\Rightarrow y^{2}_3 \cdot \left( 1 + 2 \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}\right)  - \dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}y^{2}_{4}-\dfrac{\lambda \Delta t}{\Delta x}y^{2}_{3}=  y^1_3$$

Our boundary conditions might be: $$y^n_1 = 1; y^n_4 = 3$$.
You can write this into a matrix and solve it.

To summarize, this is the easiest method but also pretty complicated and I need to advise against it for your problem because it will get really complicated with the taylor expansion but I think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a comment too long to be edited in the comments section.
$$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = c\frac{dV}{dy} - n \frac{dy}{dt}\tag 1$$
$$\frac{dV}{dy}=\frac{\frac{dV}{dt}}{\frac{dy}{dt}}$$
$$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}\frac{dy}{dt} = c\frac{dV}{dt} - n \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$$
$$\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2 = cV(t) - n \int\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2dt+C\tag 2$$
If the function $V(t)$ was known Eq.$(2)$ might be solved, at least numerically (but may be not analytically).

If $V(t)$ was known on a discret form (a series of points) an approximate analytic function $V(t)$ possibly could be defined thanks to a regression method for the parameters optimization.

Thus the problem doesn't comes from the discret function instead of a given analytic function.

The problem comes from a lack in the given data and/or a lack in the analytical representation of the physical model : There is no relationship between the time $t$ and the other variables.

In the present state of the wording of the question it seems that the solution is undetermined.